# Set Lucene Document to arbitrary id

Tags: java, search, lucene

In the 5 minute tutorial after getting the hit list

```
ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
```

Documents are obtained using

```
for(int i=0;i<hits.length;++i) {
    int docId = hits[i].doc;
    Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
    System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + d.get("isbn") + "\t" + d.get("title"));
}
```

So I see that `scoreDoc.doc` is the `docId`. Is there a way to set **this** `docId` to an arbitrary value during indexing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. And you should also **never** rely on them as they can change when updating a document or merging segments for instance.

The [FAQ](https://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#When_is_it_possible_for_document_IDs_to_change.3F) says:

> Documents can be re-numbered at anytime by Lucene
>   If you require a persistent document id, then add it as a field to your documents.

So if you need to have a known id, simply add another field to your document. Make sure the field is *stored*, then retrieve its value from the search results.

This could be as simple as an untokenized string field, or a numeric field if you need to retrieve your docs by range for instance.